# Global EventBus to pass data between components does not work

Tags: vue.js, vue-events

I am trying to use a global eventbus in VueJs but have been unsuccessful so far.

I have the following code. When I navigate from ResetPassword to Login screen, I should see the successMessage with a `Your password has been changed successfully. Please login to continue` but it always shows a blank.

What could I be doing wrong?

**plugins.js:**

```
Vue.prototype.$eventHub = new Vue();
```

**ChangePassword.vue:**

```
methods: 
  {  
    ChangePassword() 
    {
      this.$eventHub.$emit('navigation-message', 'Your password has been changed successfully. Please login to continue.');
      this.$router.push({ name: 'login'});                  
    },
  },
```

**Login.vue:**

```
data() {
    return {
      successMessage:'',
    };
  },
    created () 
      {
        this.$eventHub.$once('navigation-message', this.successMessage);
      },
      beforeDestroy() 
      {
        this.$eventHub.$off('navigation-message');
      },
```

**Update: 12/8/2019:** I changed the login.vue as per comment by @tony19 but the issue still exists.

**Login.vue:**

```
created () 
  {
    this.$eventHub.$once('navigation-message', (payload)=>
    {
      updateSuccessMessage(payload);    
    });
  },
methods: 
  { 
    updateSuccessMessage(payload) 
    {
      this.successMessage=payload;
    },
```

Comment: `this.$eventHub.$once('navigation-message', this.successMessage);` doesn't look right. The second parameter should be a function, but you've set it to `successMessage`, which is a string.

Comment: @tony19, i made the change but the issue still exists.

Comment: Does the `Login` page exist when you fire the event? If your change-password view is separate from the login view, it probably won't be created until you push the route, at which point the event listener setup is too late. I'm guessing that's what is happening.

Comment: Thank you @tony19 fir your input. I got the same input on the vuejs forums. https://forum.vuejs.org/t/global-eventbus-not-working/81641

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `this.`

```
created () {
  this.$eventHub.$on('navigation-message', payload => {
    this.updateSuccessMessage(payload) 
  })
},
methods: {
  updateSuccessMessage(payload) {
    this.successMessage = payload
  }
}
```

Also make sure you're actually importing `plugin.js` globally (e.g. inside your main file where you import `Vue`) and make sure your components have access to it.

Try this:

```
created() {
  console.log(this.$eventHub)
}
```